# How to create form Builder for Dynamic fields Angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript

I was creating fields dynamically based on Json. For example if my json array has 3 value then i will create 3 input checkbox dynamically like below

```
<ng-template ngFor let-numberOfRow [ngForOf]="numberOfRows">
   <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="numberOfRow.row" [value]="numberOfRow.row" [name]="numberOfRow.row">All</mat-checkbox>
</ng-template>
```

now i m trying to create formBuilder for this fields like below but its not working. Could someone please tell me how to declare formbuilder for dynamic fields ?

```
public ngOnInit() {
   this.myForm= this.fb.group(this.formFields);
}
public formFields() {
    let empArr = [];
    for (let val of this.myArrayList) {
        empArr.push(val + ": ''");
    }
    let allFields = '{' + empArr.join(',') + '}';
    return allFields;
}
```

basically the above formFields function will return string like this  `{ allRow: '', firstRow: '', secondRow: '', thirdRow: '' }`

so instead if declaring statically       `this.myForm= this.fb.group({ allRow: '', firstRow: '', secondRow: '', thirdRow: '' });` i want to declare the fields dynamically.

Comment: Why are you creating a string in `formFields()`? First of all if you want an object, create an object Secondly never try creating json manually, it is error prone , more work than needed and there are serializers in most languages to convert objects to json

Comment: thanks @charlietfl, i was sending data as string caused error. now passed value as Object its working fine :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per @charlietfl issue is i am sending the string data instead of object, so i send as object like below now its working fine.

```
public ngOnInit() {
    this.myForm= this.fb.group(this.formFields());
 }
 public formFields() {
     let empArr = {};
     for (let val of this.myArrayList) {
         empArr[val] = '';
     }
     return empArr;
 }
```

so the above method formField created object like `{ allRow: '', firstRow: '', secondRow: '', thirdRow: '' }` so now its working fine. Thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by first building the [FormControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControl) in code using the [control](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder#control) method of the [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormBuilder) and then using the [addControl](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#addControl) method of the [FormGroup](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup). For example like this:

```
this.myForm.addControl('controlName', 
   this.fb.control({ disabled: false, value: controlValue }, validators, asyncValidators));
```

Then you need to bind it using the [FormControlDirective](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlDirective) instead of the [FormControlName](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormControlName) directive because the control is already created. The binding will then look like this:

```
<mat-checkbox [formControl]="myForm.controls['controlName']" [value]="numberOfRow.row" [name]="numberOfRow.row">All</mat-checkbox>
```

Comment: thanks @AlesD issue is i was sending data as STRING type, so now changed to Object now working fine.

Answer (score 0):

> building with formBuilder example:

**component.ts**

```
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private fb: FormBuilder
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.form = this.fb.group({
      dropOffAddress : ['', Validators.required]
    })

  }

  addInput() {
    this.form.addControl(`input-${Object.keys(this.form.value).length}`, new FormControl('', [Validators.required]))
  }

  removeInput(key: string) {
    this.form.removeControl(key)

  }
```

**component.html**

```
<form [formGroup]="form" *ngIf="show">
  <ng-container *ngFor="let f of form.controls | keyvalue">
    <mat-form-field appearance="outline" class="w-100" color="primary">
      <mat-label>Label of Input</mat-label>
      <mat-icon (click)="addInput()" color="accent" matPrefix>add</mat-icon>
      <input type="text" [formControlName]="f.key" [name]="f.key" autofocus matInput placeholder="Digite um endereço">
      <mat-icon (click)="removeInput(f.key)" matSuffix>remove</mat-icon>
      <mat-error *ngIf="form.invalid">Please fill the field</mat-error>
    </mat-form-field>
  </ng-container>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I maintain an array with the json object fields names, and an array with the form controls, then i itterate over the field names in order to create the form checkboxes

**TypeScript file:**

```
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export class SomeComponent
{
  form!: FormGroup;
  fieldNames: string[];
  formControls: any;

  constructor(
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  )
  {
      const someJsonOnject = {env: "Dev", name: "SRV", ver: "21.1" };
      this.fieldNames= [];
      this.formControls= {};

      Object.keys(someJsonOnject).forEach(currentFieldName => {
        // add the current field name to the fieldNames array
        this.fieldNames.push(currentFieldName);

        // create a boolean formControl from each field
        this.formControls[currentFieldName] = [true];
      });
            
      // add formControls to the form
      this.form = this.formBuilder.group(this.formControls);
  }
}
```

**HTML Template file:**

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let currentFormControl of fieldNames">
        <div><mat-checkbox formControlName="{{ currentFormControl }}">{{ currentFormControl }}</mat-checkbox></div>
    </ng-container>
</form>
```